# Writing a test with multiple argument options in Jest?

Tags: angular, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'd like to execute a test where I know my argument will be one of two options.

Ideally something like so:

`expect(getFormSpy).toBeCalledWith('option1' || 'option2');`

However it seems the OR is not supported and jest is expecting option1 each time. Is there a way to make sure that jest allows both options?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved! You can add an OR inside the function call itself if you use expect.stringMatching()

```
expect(getFormSpy).toBeCalledWith(expect.stringMatching('option1' || 'option2'));
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.